Selenium/Katalon Automation- Stripe | Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
I am trying to automate a a web application where stripe is integrated. While I am on payment page try to enter the correct coupon code then it shows the following error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()".
Also, please see the attached screenshot.
Since the launched browser window is being controlled by selenium or katalon so it's giving such error. However if I copy the same URL and use the same coupon code and pay for the product for testing then it shows successful.
Is there any undetectable chrome mode available?
Note: I saw there is one for python: https://seleniumbase.io/help_docs/uc_mode/
Regards

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.
